# GitHub Actions - workflow environment variable values dependent on environment

Tags: github-actions

I am looking to have a set of workflow level environment variables that take different values depending on the environment the workflow is running on. Below is how I am looking to do this:

```
name: Test workflow file

on:
  workflow_dispatch

env:
  GH_ENV_VAR: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'main') && 'prod' || contains(github.ref, 'feature-branch') && 'dev' || 'cert' }}
  GH_ENV_VARIABLE: ${{ env.GH_ENV_VAR == 'dev' && 'DEV' || 'DO NOT KNOW'}} 
  USER_ACCOUNT: sample
  WAREHOUSE: small
```

I am seeing the following error:

**Invalid workflow file**

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/workflow-file.yml (Line: 8, Col: 20): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.GH_ENV_VAR == 'dev' && 'DEV' || 'DO NOT KNOW'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `env.` scope when creating `env` variables.

Even though it may look ok and you expect to have GH_ENV_VAR already there - it's not possible in workflows.

Comment: I found that a workaround of setting outputs in a setup job in all other jobs of a workflow works for me. I referred to documentation provided here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs

Comment: Here's an example of the workaround implementation:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26529#discussioncomment-3252224